# Comma-separation trouble

Tags: sql

In a table of mine I have data like this.

```
roolno  
-----------------------------
V658, V628
A001
A001, V003, V005, Z040
A001, V003, Z040
A001, A002
A001, A002, A003
A001, A002, A003, A004
A001, A002, A003, A004, A006
A001, A002, A003, A004, A006, A013, A015, A047, A100
A001, A002, A003, A004, A006, NULL, A046
NULL, B154, ''
C296, '', '  ', NULL, G652
```

I am trying to have value in a separate row.

For example: this is just one line i took for example

```
A001, A002, A003, A004, A006, NULL, A046
```

should be turned into:

```
A001, 
A002, 
A003, 
A004, 
A006, 
NULL,
A046
```

I have checked many posts already available on Stack Overflow, but that not giving correct result to me.

Please help.

Comment: Why do you tag SQL ? Do you want to use queries to re-format your data? Or do you prefer server-side programming languages? and what have you tried ?

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you please rephrase it?

Comment: To not store data like comma separated values is the way to go!

Comment: @Harry: i have a two table lets say Table A and Table B.

in table A cola contains values seperated with comma.
i want to arrange the element in rows and do inner join with table B. Regards

Comment: @Raptor: hi i have tried this.http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings. but it is not giving me correct result. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
 SELECT   
 Split.r.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Data  
 FROM  
 (
 SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(roolno, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
 FROM  table1
 ) AS r CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(r);
```

or if you want to put where clause you can put it like this

```
 SELECT   
 Split.r.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Data  
 FROM  
 (
 SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(roolno, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
 FROM  table1 where roolno='A001, V003, Z040'
 ) AS r CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(r);
```